# Generate Docusign Token which is valid for more time.

Tags: java, api, docusignapi

I have a DocuSign production Basic API account and I am using java SDK to generate the token.  I am following this: https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client

But the generated token is getting expired in 8 hours. Please let me know how do we generate the token using Java code that will last for a long time.

Comment: I am using same url code but it is not working.can you help me. https://gitlab.com/sanju24689/docusign

Answer (score 0):

Eight hours is the maximum lifetime of an access token. Once it has expired, you'll need to use the refresh token to request a new one.

Documentation on how to use the refresh token to obtain a new access token is available here: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant#using-refresh-tokens